# Floating text to the right side of image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float

I found a good example of doing this on Stack Overflow and used it with success to build a similar layout for product boxes in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3390qL4/1/) I copied the CSS and HTML almost verbatim to my [Wordpress blog](https://letsprint3d.net/2017/05/16/cetus3d-printer-review/) and the title/description/price no longer float next to the image but further down.

Being the case, I can only assume something else is responsible for breaking my custom styling but I am at a loss as to what. Can anyone help point me in the right direction to find and resolve the cause?

HTML:

```
<div class="info-container-left">
    [usrlist "Ease of Use:5" "Build Quality:5" "Features:4" "Price:5" "Overall:4.65" text=false]
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-thumb"><img src="https://letsprint3d.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cetus3d_base.png" /></div>
        <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-title">
                 <a href="#">Cetus3D Printer</a>
                 <div class="product-price">$299</div>
            </h3>
            <p>Compact 3D Printer with a large build volume using a form follows function design.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-thumb"><img src="https://letsprint3d.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cetus3d_extended.png" /></div>
        <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-title">
                 <a href="#">Cetus3D Extended</a>
                 <div class="product-price">$399</div>
            </h3>
            <p>Includes a longer Z-Axis, providing an extended build volume of 180x180x280mm.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.info-container-left {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
.info-container-right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    float: right;
}

.product-container {
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 100%;
}
.product-thumb {
    float: left;
}
.product-thumb img {
    display: block;
}
.product-content {
    margin-left: 90px;
}
.product-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.product-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.product-price {
    float: right;
}
```

Correct Layout (JSFiddle):

[image]

Broken Layout ([My Website](https://letsprint3d.net/2017/05/16/cetus3d-printer-review/)):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this css

```
.product-container {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;/*Add This Property*/
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.product-content {
    float: left;
    /*margin-left: 90px;*/ /*Remove This*/
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Ah excellent, that did indeed fix it, thank you so much! The only issue now is the price doesn't line up with the title anymore but rather floats below it to the right? Is that caused by using the width rather than margin-left?

Comment: there add blank p tag remove this

Comment: other way to write this css .product-title p {display:none;}

Comment: I do see those blank P tags in the inspector but they aren't in the HTML. Even looking at View Source, they aren't shown there either, it is only Inspector for some reason.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't make any sense. I use <p> tags for the "product-description" and it inserts empty <p> tags in Inspector. I switched that to div to remove those. The "product-title" is inserting a random <br> after the link though which isn't in the HTML so I have no idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145188/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-brett-powell).

Comment: Wordpress adds empty <p> when you add a line breaking in the visual editor. Even sometimes in the html editor. If you place all yout html as a single line in the html editor it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason is working on the fiddle but not in your web is because Wordpress css's, by default use `clear:both` on the headers (h1, h2...) and your `product title` is an `h3` header. Just change it for a `div` (I recomend this option) OR add:

```
.product-title {clear:inherit}
```

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense, I did not realize that. Thank you!